# How to add timestamp to Atom snippets?

Tags: atom-editor

I have been trying to figure out how to add add timestamp to Atom Snippets.

```
'.text.plain':  
  'Timestamp':  
    'prefix': 'isoT'
    'body': 'new Date().toISOString()'
```

This just prints the text and without ' it throws an error.
Is it possible to add javascript to an Atom snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Snippets are stored in a CSON file, which is CoffeeScripts equivalent of JSON.

In all likelyhood, there already exists a [package](https://atom.io/packages/search?q=timestamp) that inserts a timestamp. Otherwise, with knowledge of JavaScript, it's fairly easy to write your own. Take note that all commands provided by a package can be bound to a keystroke.